# CakePhP write Auth login/logout to debug log

Tags: authentication, logging, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to log users attempts to log in and out, but I reached a dead end. 
I am using the Auth Component in the AppController, where it sets all the $this->Auth->user data. If i log it here, it is written twice to the log and i don't know if the login was successful. If i log $this->log($this->Session->read('Auth'), 'debug'); in the login method of the UsersController, it is not yet set, so i don't get the data.

How can i get the Session data just after it's set or deleted? Any other way than extending the Auth Component?

Thank you